# Why my i2cset block write command not working

Tags: i2c, eeprom

I am trying to use i2c tools to read write to I2C devices.
i2cset block write does not seem to work. I get "Error: Too many arguments!"

byte and word writes do work.
What exactly is meant by a block? Is it 256 bytes?

The command I am using is

```
./i2cset -y  0x01 0x55 0x00 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0x00 0x9A 0x00 0xEC 0x00 i
```

- 0x01 is the bus#,
- 0x55 is the device addr#,
- 0x00 is the starting reg addr#,
- i is for block write.

Comment: Are you writing to valid register ranges? Not too many devices have this many registers.

Comment: yes. Turns out some cpus don't support block read/write operations

Answer (score 1):

Try [i2ctransfer](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/i2c-tools/i2ctransfer.8.en.html)

```
i2ctransfer [-f] [-y] [-v] [-a] i2cbus desc [data] [desc [data]] ...
```

```sh
i2ctransfer 1 w54@0x55 0x00 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0x9A 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0xCD 0x00 0x9A 0x00 0xEC 0x00
```

Answer (score 0):

**The i2cset block write success depends on the underlying I2C Linux kernel driver.**

To check if the I2C driver in your system supports block operations, use the `i2cdetect -F` as shown below:

```
$ sudo i2cdetect -F 1
Functionalities implemented by /dev/i2c-1:
I2C                              yes
SMBus Quick Command              no
SMBus Send Byte                  yes
SMBus Receive Byte               yes
SMBus Write Byte                 yes
SMBus Read Byte                  yes
SMBus Write Word                 yes
SMBus Read Word                  yes
SMBus Process Call               no
SMBus Block Write                yes
SMBus Block Read                 yes
SMBus Block Process Call         no
SMBus PEC                        no
I2C Block Write                  yes
I2C Block Read                   yes
```

For `i2cset` and `i2cget`, the I2C driver should support **SMBus Block** operations.

For `i2ctransfer`, the I2C driver should support **I2C Block** operations.

Then, the I2C client device should have a valid address range. Otherwise, the I2C transaction will fail. The I2C client device addresses in the 0x50 - 0x57 range belong to the I2C EEPROM chips. They usually support page writing.
A page write operation allows up to page-size bytes to be written in the same write cycle, provided all bytes are in the same row of the memory array. Partial page
writes of less than page-size bytes are also allowed.

Example of overriding the first 4 bytes of EEPROM chip data with new data in a single I2C write transaction performed with `i2cset` and then with `i2ctransfer`.

Read the content of the first 4 bytes:

```
$ sudo i2cset -y 1 0x57 0
$ sudo i2cget -y 1 0x57
0x00
$ sudo i2cget -y 1 0x57
0x01
$ sudo i2cget -y 1 0x57
0x02
$ sudo i2cget -y 1 0x57
0x03
```

Overwrite the `0x01020304` with `0xdeadbeef` by a single `i2cset` command:

```
$ sudo i2cset -y 1 0x57 0 0xde 0xad 0xbe 0xef i
```

Read the content of the first 4 bytes again:

```
$ sudo i2cset -y 1 0x57 0
$ sudo i2cget -y 1 0x57
0xde
$ sudo i2cget -y 1 0x57
0xad
$ sudo i2cget -y 1 0x57
0xbe
$ sudo i2cget -y 1 0x57
0xef
```

The same can be achieved with `i2ctransfer`.

Write `0xcafecafe` into the first 4 bytes of the EEPROM chip:

```
$ sudo i2ctransfer -y 1 w5@0x57 0x00 0xca 0xfe 0xca 0xfe
```

Read the content of the first 4 bytes again:

```
$ sudo i2ctransfer -y 1 w1@0x57 0 r4
0xca 0xfe 0xca 0xfe
```